# how to get number of rows froma PDO Prepare Statement?

Tags: php, pdo, prepared-statement, rows

I have this query:

```
public function checkUser($phone)
{
    $sql = "SELECT name FROM users WHERE phone=:phone";
    $stmt = db::getInstance()->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':phone', $phone);
    $stmt->execute();
    $user = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    return $user;
}
```

And I call it like this:

```
$insertUser = $data->checkUser("1234567890");
print_r($insertUser);
```

What I need to know is if the query returns a user or not. When I call `fetchAll()` I get  `array()`, but I need to be certain that a result is returned.

I tried to use `$user = $stmt->rowCount();` but I get an error that says `rowCount` is an unknown function.

Any ideas on how to grab the number of rows and test whether there are rows returned or not?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way given your current code would be:

```
$insertUser = $data->checkUser("1234567890");
$count = sizeof($insertUser);
```

Since Fetchall in your query returns ALL matching records in an array of one row per record or null if 0 records found, if the count is 0, easy--no user.  If the count is greater than 0, at least one user is found.

Answer (score 0):

You could bind the result column to the `$user` variable and then use fetch to check if a row is returned:

```
public function checkUser($phone)
{
    $sql = "SELECT name FROM users WHERE phone=:phone";
    $stmt = db::getInstance()->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':phone', $phone);
    $stmt->bindColumn('name', $name);
    $stmt->execute();
    if($stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOUND)) {
        return $name;
    } else {
        return null; //No user found
    }
}
```

Although it would probably just be easier to check if `PDOStatement::fetch()` returns false (no rows):

```
public function checkUser($phone) {
    $stmt = db::getInstance()->prepare("SELECT name FROM users WHERE phone=:phone");
    $stmt->execute(array(':phone' => $phone));
    $user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    return $user !== false; //Returns true if a row is returned, false otherwise
}
```